# Download Google Drive file to directory specified by Storage Access Framework

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, storage, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to download a Google Drive file to a directory specified by the Storage Access Framework using the *ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE* intent.

When providing a path manually I achieved this by using this Runnable.

```
private class DownloadFileThread implements Runnable {
    private String fileId;
    private String path;

    public DownloadFileThread(String fileId, String path) {
        this.fileId = fileId;
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            try {
                String filename = driveService.files().get(fileId).execute().getName();

                // content
                OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                driveService.files().get(fileId)
                    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
                String filecontent = outputStream.toString();

                // create file
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
                byte[] buffer = filecontent.getBytes();
                fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else {
            requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            }, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I started the Intent like this

```
public void downloadFileExplorer() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EXPLORER_DOWNLOAD_FILE);
}
```

And handled it in onActivityResult()

```
else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EXPLORER_DOWNLOAD_FILE) {
    DriveExplorer driveExplorer = new DriveExplorer(driveService, this);
    driveExplorer.downloadFile("1YLXh9a20_S03Gote311QLAdH1WhIDGXt", "/storage/self/primary/Download/");
}
```

Starting the Runnable

```
 public void downloadFile(String fileId, String path) {
     new Thread(new DownloadFileThread(fileId, path)).start();
 }
```

---

I can upload a chosen file like this

```
else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EXPLORER_UPLOAD_FILE) {
    DriveExplorer driveExplorer = new DriveExplorer(driveService, this);
    FileUtils fileUtils = new FileUtils(this);
    String path = fileUtils.getPath(uri);
    driveExplorer.uploadFile(path);
}
```

This workes, because the URI references the full path + filename and a Utilty Class I found online could extract the path for example: /storage/self/primary/Download/abc.txt

---

When downloading however, the URI only references the folder path and the Utility can't deal with that.
for example: /storage/self/primary/Download/

Comment: Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to create a `DocumentFile` for the user's chosen tree. Use `createFile()` on `DocumentFile` to create a `DocumentFile` representing the content that you wish to create. Call `getUri()` on that new `DocumentFile` to get a `Uri` for the document that you wish to create, and use `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` for that `Uri`. Write your content to the stream, then flush and close the stream.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you very much!